# Load another Subdomain without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, subdomain

I searched for some infos for a diffrent topic. On some sites i noticed that the url changed by scrolling. I dont know if its advertising thats why i set the examplelink as code.

```
http://www.adweek.com/digital/post-clicks-other-clicks-are-important-metrics-for-facebook-page-admins-too/
```

Does anyone know how u can change the supdomain by Javascript without refreshing? This side looks like typical Wordpress template. I have no experience and i´m not interested to learn something about wordpress. But its a nice way to generate more clicks on an website.

I tried something like that by JS:

```
var screenHei = height settings; /*must be changed*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>screenHei){                    
            ***change the subdomain             
        }       
    }
})
```

Anyone an idea? And has anyone some experience by SEO with that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't use JavaScript it's actually an HTML5 API `history.pushState()`

You can check this tutorial for more info: [Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Or the official [MDN page on Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)